# LibVLC on android not update SurfaceTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, libvlc

We would like to integrate libvlc in our project, replacing Android MediaPlayer.

Project compile, libvlc is initialized withput error but nothing happens.

Instead of render video on a android widget as SurfaceView, GLSurfaceView or TextureView, we musto to render to a SurfaceTexture which GL texture creted in JNI part. We are using this texture to render a sky dome in our game.

Right now we are decoding video to texture with android MediaPlayer and run perfectly. So issues is related with libVLC integration. No trace logs are written so is quite difficult so find where the problem is.

To summary our code:

1 - Set up libvlc library

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity

libVLC = new LibVLC(options);
libVLC.setOnNativeCrashListener(this);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
mediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);
```

2 - Load movie source

```
if (mediaPath.startsWith("http")) {
    media = new Media(libVLC, mediaUri);
    this.isLoaded = (media.parse(Media.Parse.FetchNetwork) && getMediaInformation()) || 
                    (media.parse(Media.Parse.ParseNetwork) && getMediaInformation());       
} else if (mediaPath.startsWith("android.resource://")) {
    media = new Media(libVLC, mediaUri);
} else {
    media = new Media(libVLC, mediaPath);
    this.isLoaded = (media.parse(Media.Parse.FetchLocal) && getMediaInformation()) ||     
                    (media.parse(Media.Parse.ParseLocal) && getMediaInformation()); 
}
```

3 - Update texture in render loop

```
synchronized(this) {
    if(isFrameNew) {
        if(surfaceTexture != null) surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            isFrameNew = false;
            isMoviedone = false;
            return true;
    } 
    return false;    
}
```

But nothing. Texture is empty and seems that libvlc is not working internally.

Anyone has the same issue?

Thank in advanced

Comment: Have you asked this in vlc android forum? You may get quick help there from vlc developers. https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=35

Comment: Yes I hava also published it in vlc-android forum.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Did you get anywhere on the vlc android forum? I can't find your question.

Comment: Found your question on the libvlc forums, did you find any useful samples? All I can find is this one ( or copies of it ) https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample and it uses android view components - I just want to use SurfaceTexture like yourself.

Comment: Not any samples. We change libVLC to a java-JNI using exoplayer :(. It's works quite well